# Subtracting count of two different columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following table

```
Table A
UploadDate  Destroy
12/23/2020   1
12/31/2025   0
11/11/2020   1
12/16/2021   1
```

I have aroud 1000 rows like this. I need to write a SQL statement where count(uploadDate) - count of destroy where destroy=1 so in the above case, it will be 4-3. I want 1 to be returned by the query. Bedlow is the create table statement:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table_A](
    [UploadDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [Destroyed] [bit] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

below are the insert statement for some sample data:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table_A]
           ([UploadDate]
           ,[Destroyed])
     VALUES
           ('12/23/2020'
           ,1)



INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table_A]
           ([UploadDate]
           ,[Destroyed])
     VALUES
           ('12/22/2020'
           ,0)

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table_A]
           ([UploadDate]
           ,[Destroyed])
     VALUES
           ('12/31/2020'
           ,0)
        

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table_A]
           ([UploadDate]
           ,[Destroyed])
     VALUES
           ('11/11/2020'
           ,1)


         INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table_A]
           ([UploadDate]
           ,[Destroyed])
     VALUES
           ('12/16/2021'
           ,1)
```

This is what I have so far:

```
select count(uploadDate) - count(Destroyed)
from document
where destroyed=1
```

Comment: `COUNT(CASE WHEN destroy <> 1 THEN 1 END)` maybe? How is `UploadDate` relevant to the question?

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: I edited the code to include insert and create table statement.

Comment: I still don't get how `UploadDate` is relevant to the question. Please explain any logic that might involve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use `COUNT(CASE WHEN destroyed = 1 THEN 1 END)` to find the count of rows where `destroyed = 1`.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) - 
       COUNT(CASE WHEN destroyed = 1 THEN 1 
END) AS RES
FROM Table_A
```

See a demo from [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=efd6c264067b4a621f23d0605edae9db).